# terraform .12 - add multiple inline policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am wondering if there is an easy way to add multiple json file policies

mypolicy1.json,
mypolicy2.json,
mypolicy3.json

as of now this is my code.. works great for one policy

```
variable "iam_policy_path" {
  default = "./mypolicy.json"  
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "role" {
  name   = var.name
  role   = var.role
  policy = file(var.iam_policy_path)
}
```

```
module "aws_iam_role_policy" {
   source = "../modules/mypolicypolicy/"
   name = "mypolicy"
   role = module.myrole.myroleout
   iam_policy_path = "new_policy_path.json"
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the correct approach would be to have one policy that has all the needed policy-statements?

Comment: Still learning the terraform best ways. For non terraform we add many in-lines to role. I kind of like that approach because it is easier to understand at a glance. Not sure if I’ll achieve that but it is what it is.

Comment: @bsapaka In my mind, for software in general, any approach that prevents you from creating sensible abstractions is never "correct," even if the people who created the tool or the primary community for that tool say otherwise.

That isn't the case here though. If you have a resource that a lot of other resources use, having a policy for that resource that those other resources share is simply sensible, and the huge number of AWS managed policies shows that they totally expect people to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) and having your `iam_policy_path` being a list of paths.

For example:

```
variable "iam_policy_path" {
  default = ["./mypolicy.json", "./mypolicy2.json"]  
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "role" {
  
  for_each = toset(var.iam_policy_path) # for each requires set. 
 
  name   = var.name
  role   = var.role

  policy = file(each.key)
}
```

Then when using the module:

```
module "aws_iam_role_policy" {
   source = "../modules/mypolicypolicy/"
   name = "mypolicy"
   role = module.myrole.myroleout
   iam_policy_path = ["new_policy_path.json", "new_policy_path2.json"]
}
```

Based on the extra info. The complete solution may require also using [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment) which attaches a managed policy to a role.

Comment: when I added it this code, it will add one of the two  the json files,  when i do a TF apply there is only one of the two json added. Than if I run an apply again, it sees changes than it replaces the first json file with the next on my list and keeps replacing  over and over if i ran an apply.

Comment: So i was able to use your exact code..a tweak here and there to add >1 AWS managed policies using "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" resource. so clearly your code is good, but it just is weird on how it is dealing within inline policies.

Comment: ok, ill see what i can figure out... thanks for all the help